# When a faithful linear Lie algebra representation preserves composition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ with the basis
$$
x=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},~y=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},~h=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.
$$
From [Humphreys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAijj.png), on classification of irreducible $L$-modules [(7.2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2npam.png):

> $\quad$ One further observation: The symmetry in the structure of $V(m)$ can be made more obvious if we exploit the discussion of *exponentials* in $(2.3)$. Let $\phi : L \to \mathfrak{gl}(V(m))$ be the irreducible representation of highest weight $m$. Then $\phi(x), \phi(y)$ are nilpotent endomorphisms, in view of the formulas above, so we can define an automorphism of $V(m)$ by $\tau = \exp \phi(x) \exp \phi(-y) \exp \phi(x)$. We may as well assume $m \gt 0$, so the representation is faithful ($L$ begin simple). The discussion in $(2.3)$ shows that conjugating $\phi(h)$ by $\tau$ has precisely the same effect as applying $\exp (\text{ad}\ \phi(x)) \exp (\text{ad}\ \phi(-y))$$ \exp(\text{ad}\ \phi(x))$ to $\phi(h)$. But $\phi(L)$ is isomorphic to $L$, so this can be calculated just as in $(2.3)$. Conclusion: $\tau\phi(h)\tau^{-1} = -\phi(h)$, or $\tau\phi(h)=-\phi(h)\tau$. From this we see at once that $\tau$ sends the basis vector $v_i$ of weight $m-2i$ to the basis vector $v_{m-i}$ of weight $-(m-2i)$. (The discussion in $(2.3)$ was limited to the special case $m=1$.) More generally, if $V$ is any finite dimensional $L$-module, then $\tau$ interchanges positive and negative weight spaces.

1. I'm trying to verify that $\tau\phi(h)\tau^{-1}=-\phi(h)$. Is it true that $\phi^{-1}(\tau\phi(h)\tau^{-1})=\exp(x)\exp(-y)\exp(x)h(\exp(x)\exp(-y)\exp(x))^{-1}$? It is seen from (2.3) that the last equals to $-h$. So applying $\phi$ should lead to the result if $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ preserve composition of matrices.
2. Don't we need irreducibility of $\phi$ here?

Comment: I mean that $\phi^{-1}\colon \phi(L)\to L$ because $L\cong\phi(L)$, @DietrichBurde

Comment: By preserving composition I mean $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$

Comment: This does not hold. $\phi$ is only a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Comment: We assume here that dimension of $\phi$ is more than $1$: $m>0$, $m+1=\dim V(m)$, @DietrichBurde

Comment: Why $\phi(L)=\mathfrak{gl}(V(4))$? $\ker\phi$ is subalgebra of simple algebra $L$, so $\ker\phi=0$ because otherwise $\phi$ is trivial, so $\phi$ is injective @DietrichBurde

Comment: I'm not sure if this ever happens except in trivial cases. Note, an abstract Lie algebra doesn't even have an idea of composition. You are imposing a representation by writing it as matrices and there's no reason transitioning between two representations should preserve composition of matrices.